# Hidden value included when putting ebx register into a DD variable

Tags: assembly, 32-bit, cpu-registers

At one moment while executing my code with Turbo Debugger, my `bx` register has a `0001` value in it.

(I can only view `bx` register in Turbo Debugger, and could not find how to view a whole `ebx`. Side question: how to view whole eax/ebx/... registers? )

Immediately after, when I send `ebx` to a `DD` variable `sum1`, the sent value becomes `30310001h`.

What are the reasons for it and how can I avoid it?

My only guess for a reason: `sum1` recieved an invisible value, which is included in `ebx` but not `bx` (contained by `ebx`).

(I am new to ebx/eax/... registers btw.)

If I guessed right, then how can I access that unseen part of `ebx`?

This is the shortened code, the `loop2a` converts a string into a decimal value, char-by-char, and puts it into `ebx`.

```
loop2a:
    mov     eax, [di]
    mov     ah, 0
    sub     eax, '0'

    imul    eax, ecx
    add     ebx, eax
    mov     sum1, ebx

    imul    ecx, ten      

    dec     di

    cmp     di, a
    jne     loop2a

    mov     sum1, ebx
```

(Compiler: Turbo Assembler, processor: Intel x86.)

Comment: Please include a relevant excerpt of your code into your problem statement rather than a link to the entire thing. Be mindful that the `e__` registers are 32-bit registers. So `ebx` is 32 bits, and `bx` is 16 bits (and represents the lower 16 bits of `ebx`). If you put something into `bx`, the top 16 bits of `ebx` are not automatically set to zero. If you subsequently move `ebx` to a `dd` location (which is a 32 bit location) you'll get whatever happens to be in the high 16 bits. If you want to move a 16-bit register to a 32-bit, you might want to look up the `movzwl` instruction.

Comment: Presumably you are using the 16 bit debugger. Switch to the 32 bit version.

Comment: @ lurker What is `ebx` split into? `bx` and...? What represents its upper 16 bits?

Comment: You can't access the top 16 bits directly. You can shift or rotate it down.

Comment: There is no register that represents only the upper 16 bits of `ebx`. So it doesn't split into `bx` and something else.

Comment: I cannot reference your links. Our firewall blocks them.

Comment: @lurker added code from link to question.

Comment: *how to view whole eax/ebx/... registers?* Click on a register and highlight it. Then push the **right** mouse button. You'll get a menu. Click on "Registers 32-bit No". Voilà. CTRL-R does the same.

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere in your code you initialized `BX` (`xor bx,bx` or `mov bx,0`). Just change it to `EBX` (`xor ebx,ebx` or `mov ebx,0`). You cannot separately access the upper word of a 32-bit-register.